# When does django calculate properties that aren't stored in the DB

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Quick question about performance. Let's say we have some model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def getComplicatedNumber(self):
        # do some complex calculations here, including other db calls
        return 0 # really return the complex calculation

    otherNum = property(getComplicatedNumber)
```

Then let's say we have in a view:

`modelObject.otherNum`

or in a template:

`{{ modelObject.otherNum }}`

My question is, when is this attribute/property calculated when an object with the property is created? Is it only calculated when it is called in the view or template, or is it calculated whenever that object is retrieved or when an instance of that class is created? I imagine this would slow down performance if it is being calculated often and not used in views or templates.

Thanks

Comment: The property is calculated *each time* you fetch it, so it is not calculated in advance, not (by default) cached. But you can of course implement a caching mechanism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is, when is this attribute/property calculated when an object with the property is created? Is it only calculated when it is called in the view or template, or is it calculated whenever that object is retrieved or when an instance of that class is created?

It is calculated *each time* you fetch it. So if you write:

```
modelObject.otherNum  # call getComplicatedNumber() the first time
modelObject.otherNum  # call getComplicatedNumber() the second time
```

the `getComplicatedNumber` is called *twice*.

It is *not* calculated in advance (so if you never need the property, you will never calculate it), nor is it *cached* (once calculated, the value is not stored to prevent calculating it a second time).

You can of course implement a cache like:

```
# possible implementation of a cache

class MyModel(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def getComplicatedNumber(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_complicated'):
            # do some complex calculations here, including other db calls
            self._complicated = 0  # really return the complex calculation
        return self._complicated

    otherNum = property(getComplicatedNumber)
```

Note however that if the attributes and parameters on which the method depends change, the cache will *not* automatically get invalidated.

This cached version will *not* calculate the value if you do not need it.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the answer. Thanks for the tip about the cache, that's probably a great way to improve performance, especially if that method is doing a lot of db calls.